# Number of k-combinations of a set of size n for which k varies between min and max

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given:

- Set of size `n`
- Select elements (unordered, no duplicates) from that set
- Select `k` elements, for which `min <= k < max`

Question: How many k-combinations are there?

If `k` were a fixed number, [wikipedia has the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination): `n! / (k! (n-k)!)`
Unfortunately, it's not.

For example:

- Given the set `[A, B, C, D, E]`, select at least `2` and at most `3` elements.
- So `n=5`, `min=2`, `max=4`, `2 <= k < 4`.
- Number of combinations: `6!/2!4! + 6!/3!3! = 720/48 + 720/36 = 35`

So `35` combinations. What's the general formula given `n`, `min`, `max`?

Comment: Why `k < max` rather than `k <= max`?

Comment: You probably have to do the sum except where there are shortcuts such as using Pascal's triangle to note `6!/2!4! + 6!/3!3! = 7!/3!4!`

Comment: @Henry: `k <= max` is fine too. As for the sum, at least the `n!/(min! (n-max)!)` can be extracted?