# Simplify sum with factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any way to simplify this?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{b}\left (\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\right)$$

Edit: Assume that $b \le n$

(Side note: relates to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783457/number-of-k-combinations-of-a-set-of-size-n-for-which-k-varies-between-min-and-m).)

Comment: Unless $b=n,n/2$ or other nice values, there is no way to simplify this sum. As in, there is no closed form expression for it.

Comment: I wonder if you might have intended $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^b$ rather than $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^b$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, I don't want the empty collection included, but if it's included, I can easily count it out (+1) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has actually been asked quite a few times on this site: And the answer is that there is no closed form expression for the partial sum of binomial coefficients.

Comment: Is it proven that no such closed form exists? Is it even possible to prove that no closed form exists for an expression?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: [Three](http://digbib.ubka.uni-karlsruhe.de/volltexte/181894) [useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103280/asymptotics-for-a-partial-sum-of-binomial-coefficients) [links](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n).

Answer (score 3):

From
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n}
\end{align}
then it is seen that (the case of $b=n$)
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n} -1.
\end{align}
Now, if $b < n$ and integer, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{b} \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n} -1 - \sum_{k=b+1}^{n} \binom{n}{k}.
\end{align}
if $b > n$ and integer then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{b} \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n} -1 + \sum_{k=n+1}^{b} \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n} -1
\end{align}
since $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k >n$.

Comment: `b <= n`, so it looks like I am still stuck with the non-closed form.